# How search for item in specific folder and get its properties with sharepoint online REST API?

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have to search in specific subfolder on sharepoint online for file with title.

Right now I am using the following call

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('MyDoc3')/items?$select=FileRef&$filter=substringof(%27test2.docx%27,FileRef)
```

But here I am passing a list title to get the file ref as output. How can I search in specific folder by url and get the same output as above call?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regular Expressions to extract the list name from the URL- and then use the list name in the above query

Answer (score 0):

You could use below GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl endpoint to get specific libray folder by relative url like below and select the file server relative url which is the same as FileRef.

Below get the default Document library root folder:

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/dev/Shared%20Documents')/files?$select=ServerRelativeUrl
```

[image]

Reference:

[Working with folders and files with REST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest)